# Check if any file exist in a folder when traversing through it

Tags: bash, files, directory

I have this script:

```
  local_dir="/some/dir1/"

  cd $local_dir
  for i in *.*
  do

    # do something ........
    # [...........]

    rm $i
  done
```

It throws an error when the folder is empty.

```
*: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '*': No such file or directory
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your original code, then you just need to check if file exists, using an if condition, i.e.:

```
local_dir="/some/dir1/"

cd $local_dir
for i in *.*
do
  if [[ -f "$i" ]]
  then
   # do something ........
   # [...........]

   rm $i
  fi
done
```

Comment: A simple -f doesn't need doubled [], and don't forget that you'll miss files that don't have a . in them.

Comment: @stolenmoment, what's needed?

Comment: Just "if [ -f $i ]" will do, and * should get all files, not just files with a . In the name.

Comment: IOW, `[[...]]` is not POSIX, but `[...]` is POSIX.

Answer (score -1):

try with ls

```
for i in $(ls)
do
       # Do something
rm $i
done
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is too tricky to get right. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/117549 for one example.